# to get checked items from listview and store it in array

Tags: java, android

I am new to android..please help me.
how to get the checked items from listview and store it an array and display it in another listview in the next layout in the same activity?pls help....

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are using listView with check box then you can follow this

linkhttp://appfulcrum.com/?p=281

Answer (score 0):

Rather than create checked list box, create custom list view. You can easily detect whether checked box is checked or not.